# Publishing Options for Content Type Not Showing

Tags: nodes

I am on version 9.3.2.  When I change the Publishing Options for any content type, nothing changes on the node's edit page or the new content page.  Not sure when this changed, but a year ago it was working.

Any idea how to get the publishing options to show up as expected once again?

Comment: And you checked your page as admin user or also any other user role?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as admin with full permissions. No change I make to any Content Type Publishing Option gets reflected in a node new or edit page.

Comment: Do you have any workflow-related modules enabled?  Many of those modules can hide the publishing options.  Also if you changed the admin theme, try switching to one of the default themes to make sure that your theme isn't interfering.